# Open a Mailbox then Maximize the Newly-Opened Mailbox Window

Tags: vba, outlook

The title is pretty self-explanatory.

I want the macro to open a specific mailbox and then maximize that newly created explorer window so that the mailbox that was just opened is full-screen.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Sub openMasterfiles()

    ' Define Variables
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    ' Set objects
    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = olNS.Folders("Masterfiles").Folders("Inbox")
    
    ' Display the second mailbox
    myFolder.Display
    
    ' ###Atttempting to set the new mailbox to the active explorer here
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myFolder
    
    ' Attempting to maximize the newly opened mailbox here. This code _
        only maximizes the exisiting explorer. Not the new one.
    Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMaximized
       
    
End Sub
```

All this manages to accomplish is to open the new mailbox ("Masterfiles") and maximize the ***prior*** Outlook window, not the newly opened one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get the `Inbox` folder you need to use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile.

If you need to get the `Inbox` folder from an additional store you can use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument.

But the key thing here is that you need to use the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activate(method)) method of the `Explorer` class which activates an explorer window by bringing it to the foreground and setting keyboard focus.

```
' Display the second mailbox
myFolder.Display
    
Set Application.Explorers.Item(2).CurrentFolder = myFolder

Application.Explorers.Item(2).Activate
    
' Attempting to maximize the newly opened mailbox here. This code _
  only maximizes the exisiting explorer. Not the new one.
Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMaximized
```

You may also check whether it is a second explorer window checking the `Explorers.Count` property which returns an integer indicating the count of objects in the specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Explorers.Add`, which takes `MAPIFolder` as an argument:

```
set expl = Application.Explorers.Add(myFolder, olFolderDisplayNormal)
expl.Display
expl.WindowState = olMaximized
```